# Does our universe have an even distribution of matter in every direction

Tags: cosmology, newtonian-gravity, matter

It occurred to me that it does since gravity in the space I exist appears to be uniform Ie there is no net movement of objects I observe in a particular direction. I  maybe speaking from classical Newtonian explanation of space and the matter within it. I Have no schooling in Einsteins relativity and his theory but it seems entirely plausible that the universe is uniform since we are able to calculate with accuracy the movement and paths of local objects in the space we occupy by the force of gravity between them and the kinetic energy and direction of force we have given them. These calculations surely would have an perturbation between the calculation and what's observed. This perturbation would be a result of the causal difference in a universe that has an uneven distribution of matter and the gravitational effect that uneven distribution of matter has upon the local objects and every other object in the universe.

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of matter is highly uneven in the "local" universe. Dark matter appears to be concentrated in and around galaxies and in clusters on scales of tens to thousands of kpc, and probably forms even larger filamentary structures which lead to the large scale structure we see on very big scales (tens of Mpc). I attach a picture below of a projected slice of the relatively nearby universe taken from the 2df galaxy redshift survey. Does this look uniform?

[image: 2df galaxy distribution]

All around us we see galaxies in motion with respect to each other - Andromeda is heading towards us, galaxies are orbiting in the local group, the local group is moving towards the Virgo cluster.

These motions are of course superimposed on the general Hubble expansion, but even so you have to declare a very large scale (hundreds of Mpc) before you can argue that a box will contain the same amount of matter wherever you place it.

Even then, a recent claim, is that the large "cold spot" in the cosmic microwave background may be due to a large "void" or under-density of about 10%, with a scale of 400 Mpc (http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3622).

So, to say the universe is uniform would be a vast simplification, though one that is often convenient in cosmology. The truth is more complicated and nuanced, and after all, the universe would be very boring if it really were uniform. Everything interesting tends to happen because of non-uniformity.

Comment: I am not implying an opinion that the universe is uniform i am merely stating facts that imply the universe is uniform. We

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8State and I'm saying that there is little evidence for uniformity. It is a fact that we see galaxies arranged in groups, clusters, superclusters etc. and a fact that we see almost everything, including ourselves, in motion with respect to all other objects in the universe, including the cosmic microwave background. If the universe is uniform, then the definition has to be very loose, or confined to very large scales.

Answer (score 1):

> Does our universe have an even distribution of matter in every direction

In physics we have to define our terms. In this case, universe, matter and the dimensions in which we define direction, and define what we mean by uniformity.

If we take universe to be the [observable universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe),  dimension of the order of billions of light years and units of matter as super clusters of Galaxies we can see :

[image: observable universe]

> Visualization of the whole observable universe. The scale is such that the fine grains represent collections of large numbers of superclusters. The Virgo Supercluster – home of Milky Way – is marked at the center, but is too small to be seen.

You can see granularity in this image, and a definition of uniformity within the bounds would need large +/- bands.

> It occurred to me that it does since gravity in the space I exist appears to be uniform Ie there is no net movement of objects I observe in a particular direction.

This does not make sense. There is a net movement of forces, things fall under gravity, on earth, or rotate around each other in the solar system. It is as Rob's answer states.

> Within contained heated fluids there can be a movement of flow in a particular direction but the contents 0f that fluid remain constant and the mass distribution remains unchanged cannot it be reasoned that the galaxies and there contents are moving in a similar manner and as such will have a similar uniformity.

In the [Big Bang model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) of cosmology matter and energy were in a type of fluid at very early times,  and there one  talks of uniformity that finally produced the relative uniformity in  the obseved granularity of galactic clusters. But there it is the realm of General relativity not of the gravitational forces you are imagining.

Answer (score -1):

The universe is as far as we know, generally uniform. That is, if we "zoom out" it all looks more or less the same.